# Installing Python on Unity

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, pyside

I have already done all the steps which allows me to find and select "Python for Unity" in the list of packages, but it doesn't show for some reason.

Here is a screenshot of the instructions, the site which it needed to appoera and the results of the instalation of pyside6. I think it should explain everything

https://gyazo.com/7fa03c9d5f8420dd3347d46faefeeec3

Comment: Note the minimum requirements for the Unity version and compare it against what you're running. `2020 < 2021`.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 2021.2:

1. Open the Package Manager window.
2. Click the "+" dropdown and select "Add package by name".
3. Enter `com.unity.scripting.python`, and click Add.

See this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@6.0/manual/installation.html